# How to make my acer 5742G connect to network

Tags: networking

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Acer
It will not connect to wireless or wired network.
 Very hard to copy paste output as I have no connection to the net from ubuntu

The net work from my win7 and my phone and actually once when I booted from my stick "try ubunyu" it worked fine, so HW is OK

But wired network will not connect and the wireless seems very hard

any clues

Answer (score 0):

SO I had the great same issue with my Acer 5742G and Ubuntu 13.10 latest upgrade. After some long reading and search i found  [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx).

This worked for me hope it does for you too